Nextjs/Github Pages - Images Load in Dev but Not in Prod
I am using Next.js with Tailwind CSS and am trying to set a background image for a div. The image will load in development but not in production (I am deplying to Github pages). I have other images in the same folder that do load properly. Below is what my source code looks like:
<div style={{ background: `url('./images/projects/bouncy-bouncy-proj.png')`, ...}}></div>

The image is stored in .public/images/projects

See full file structure here https://imgur.com/a/Pa0BTSj
I tried importing the image as well:
import img from './images/projects/bouncy-bouncy-proj.png'

But got the following error

Here is my tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        burtons: "burtons",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
      backgroundSize: {
        'size-200': '200% 200%',
      },
      backgroundPosition: {
          'pos-0': '0% 0%',
          'pos-100': '100% 100%',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

I have 4-5 other images located in the same .public/images/projects folder that I had been using previously and work in both dev and production, but any new images I add to the project do not load in production.
EDIT: Added imgur image for full file structure

Can you send a photo of the full file structure?

Updated with imgur image of full file structure

just make sure you have pushed the new image(s) to the remote server

Yep, that was it.. My images were pushed to the remote server, but looks like their names weren't updated properly between my side and remote side. It's fixed now thank you

Comment by @yasin helped me see the issue was my images on the remote server were not synced with my changes locally.
Somehow my image file extensions were set to ".PNG" instead of ".png" on GitHub.

I found and fixed this a while ago on my side, but it never updated on GitHub.
To fix, I removed the file extensions from the images, pushed the changes, added the extension ".png" back, and then pushed again.
Seems github is case insensitive when it comes to file name changes.
